# How to define a probability distribution over a function space?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

What is the mathematically rigorous way of defining a probability distribution over some function space e.g. $L^1[0,1]$?

**Edit:** After reading about the basics of measure theory, I realized that the first step is to define σ-algebra over $L^1$. Is there like a "standard" σ-algebra over $L^1$? Could you provide an example?

Comment: The same as always: define a finite measure on $L^1$, then describe all measurable subsets of $L^1$.